What does the word "Eine" mean in Latin?
I've searched on the web and haven't found a meaning for it, Most websites assume it is a German word. I saw it on the phrase:

Eine ego ut adverser?

This phrase is from an example in the book "Gramática Latina Napoleão Mendes de Almeida" page 395, paragraph 423. The paragraph talks about questions constructed with the future perfect and gives this as an example.
I could not find the verb whose future perfect in Latin is "eine" in the web and adverser is on the present, subjunctive and passive.

This is actually two words together: eī-ne.
The second part of this is known as an enclitic, and there are three of them in Latin: -ne, -ve, and -que. They attach to the end of the preceding word, and usually are written as part of it without any space.

it is just weird that there is no future in this sentence then, but thanks, that makes sense

@hellofriends Actually, it's about the potential subjunctive in Latin. Latin doesn't have a future in the subjunctive as Portuguese. I suggest you read that part calmly. By the way, I have this grammar, too. You have to read it with attention.
